# Where / How to get a BootCamp upgrade

Tags: mac, boot-camp

A new version/upgrade to bootcamp was announced by Apple. 
But how do I profit from new drivers on an existing bootcamp system? (XP on an mid2007 MBP)

- A "update apple software" running under windows said there was nothing new..
- I failed to find downloads on apple.com

Feeling stupid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this page at apple:

http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/

on the right of that page, near the top, are links to 32 and 64 bit upgrades for BootCamp.

Now why didn't I see that earlier today ...

Comment: It's funny, only your answer here helped me find it myself.